# Preg_match to catch dot(.) more than 3 times

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

If I wanted to verify if my string has 3 or more dots (.) I would write this regex

```
if(preg_match("/^[\.]{3}+$/", $string){
    echo "Match!";
```

'Cause the back slash indicates to verify my dot and the {3} would say the numbers os dots I would want. It would be pretty simple if it worked. Perhaps am I missing something here?

Comment: That's looking for three `.` in a row. You'd want `if(preg_match_all('/\./', $string) >= 3){}` to tell you whether there are 3 or more `.` in your string

Comment: Sounds interesting, but what if they were split among the string? It does verify all the dots with the parameter, which is good for a specific purpose.. anyway thanks man

Comment: Yeah, that's what this does, it finds all occurrences of `.` in the string, no matter whether they're together or not

Comment: `{3}+` doesn't mean 3 or more but exactly three (and make the quantifier possessive that is useless for an exact number). `{3,}` means three or more. But note that you only need to check with `{3}` to know that.

Comment: and your `^` and `$` anchors require your input string to be only dots.  Do you mean this?  and `\ ` is not necessary inside of a character class `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most directly, just ask php to count the dots (nothing more).  This does not make replacements, it does not generate an array, it doesn't count any other characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/88Hfp))

```
$strings = ['This is. a. test.',
            'This is a. test.',
            'This is. a test',
            'This is a test',
            'This. is. a. test.'
           ];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (($dots = substr_count($string, '.')) >= 3) {  // assign count as variable and make comparison
        echo "Yes, 3 or more dots ($string -> $dots)";
    } else {
        echo "Nope, less than 3 dots ($string -> $dots)";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Yes, 3 or more dots (This is. a. test. -> 3)
Nope, less than 3 dots (This is a. test. -> 2)
Nope, less than 3 dots (This is. a test -> 1)
Nope, less than 3 dots (This is a test -> 0)
Yes, 3 or more dots (This. is. a. test. -> 4)
```

---

If you want to check if there are 3 in a row, use `strpos()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1u2Nu))

```
$strings = ['This is. a. test.',
            'This is a........... test.',
            'This is. a test',
            'This is a test',
            'This. is... a. test.'
           ];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (($offset = strpos($string, '...')) !== false) {
        echo "Yes, found 3 in a row ($string -> $offset)";
    } else {
        echo "Nope, no occurrence of 3 dots in a row ($string)";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Nope, no occurrence of 3 dots in a row (This is. a. test.)
Yes, found 3 in a row (This is a........... test. -> 9)
Nope, no occurrence of 3 dots in a row (This is. a test)
Nope, no occurrence of 3 dots in a row (This is a test)
Yes, found 3 in a row (This. is... a. test. -> 8)
```

---

---

If you want to specify that exactly 3 dots exist consecutively, you can use regex:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5ceZt))

```
$strings = ['This is. a.. test...',
            'This is a........... test.',
            '...This is. a.. ..test',
            'This is a test',
            'This. is... a. test.'
           ];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match('~(?<!\.)\.{3}(?!\.)~', $string)) {
        echo "Yes, found an occurrence of not more than 3 dots in a row ($string)";
    } else {
        echo "Nope, no occurrence of exactly 3 dots in a row ($string)";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Yes, found an occurrence of not more than 3 dots in a row (This is. a.. test...)
Nope, no occurrence of exactly 3 dots in a row (This is a........... test.)
Yes, found an occurrence of not more than 3 dots in a row (...This is. a.. ..test)
Nope, no occurrence of exactly 3 dots in a row (This is a test)
Yes, found an occurrence of not more than 3 dots in a row (This. is... a. test.)
```

Comment: @E.Akio does this do everything that you require?

Comment: If I got it right, you gave me 1 - to count how many dots are on string, 2 - if there is '...' on my string, and 3 - if there are exactly 3 dots together, not more nor less. First, thanks a lot for the codes, I learned a lot now. Second, my problem is if there are 3 or more dots in a row. Particularly I think the second method would suppress my need but how could I say to the regex a 3 for more indicators of what I want? (the dot in this case)

Comment: If you are trying to determine if at least one occurrence of 3-or-more dots exists in your string -- do not use regex.  Use my 2nd method, it is the leanest/fastest.

Answer (score 3):

for only one character from the ascii range, you can use the count_chars function that returns an array with the number of occurrence for each character:

```
if ( count_chars($string)[46] > 3 ) {
    ...
```

46 is the decimal value for the dot.

Note that to make it more readable, you can write:

```
$char = ord('.');
if ( count_chars($string)[$char] > 3 ) {
    ...
```

Comment: But what if I want to count if there are 3 or more in a row? count_chars would give me the number but no specify if there are sequences of this char on my string, right?

Comment: @E.Akio Then use `strpos($str, '...') !== false`

Comment: @E.Akio I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace` and not have to worry about regex at all.

```
str_replace('.', '', 'one.two.three.', $count);
echo $count;
```

https://3v4l.org/Rl6Se

Comment: Yes, I was writing this when he added the `ord` approach. I was offering an alternative to knowning your asciis. I like it with the `ord`. Your solution also is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I changed my mind.  Casimir's answer generates an array of all characters and their counts then isolates one.  That is overkill.  And I'll agree that it impacts readability/comprehension to leverage the ascii value to target the dots.